# JavaScript/JQuery - on Click smoot scroll to ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

My intention is to implement a smooth scroll behaviour but I'm new into JS/JQuery.
When I click to my navbar anchor tag the page is scrolling down to the section with the corresponding ID. To do this I have done like this:

**HTML**

```
<a onClick="scroller(products)">
```

**JavaScript/JQuery**

```
//get the element
var products = $('#products');
var sustainibility = $('#sustainibility');
var textile = $('#textile');
var platform = $('#platform');

//get default verticalPositionOfElement
var verticalPositionOfElement = products.offset().top;

function scroller(element) { //param = the current element
    verticalPositionOfElement = element.offset().top; //to override vertical position of the element
    $(window).scrollTop(verticalPositionOfElement - 168);
};
```

From now what I have to do is to add a smooth scroll behaviour but I'm not understanding how to do it. Some ideas? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to put in CSS to body,HTML scroll-behavior: smooth eg.

```
body,html{
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

You have an example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Now it works good.

```
//get the element
var products = $('#products');
var sustainibility = $('#sustainibility');
var textile = $('#textile');
var platform = $('#platform');

//get default verticalPositionOfElement
var verticalPositionOfElement = products.offset().top;

function scroller(element) { //param = the current element

verticalPositionOfElement = element.offset().top; //to override vertical position of the element

//smooth scroll
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($(element).offset().top) - 168
}, 100);
};
```